# Catch error ChangePassword in react native

Tags: react-native, setstate

Im trying to catch the error (for example, "The password is invalid or the user doent not have a password") but it does not work..
How can I resolve it?

Another question, when I come back to this screen, I want to have empty fields (newPassord and currentPassword), but it also does not work..

ChangePassword.js :

```
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={
            newPassword:'',
            currentPassword:''
        };
    }


    reauthenticate=(currentPassword)=>{
        var user=firebase.auth().currentUser;
        var cred=firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.credential(user.email,currentPassword);
        return user.reauthenticateWithCredential(cred);
    }

    ChangePassword=()=>{
        if(this.state.currentPassword==="" || this.state.newPassword==="")
        {
            alert("All the fields are required")
        }
        else{
            try{
                this.reauthenticate(this.state.currentPassword).then(()=>
                {
                    var user=firebase.auth().currentUser;
                    user.updatePassword(this.state.newPassword)
                    .then(alert("Password has been changed"))                    
                    const response = firebase.database().ref(user.uid);
                    if(response){
                            this.props.navigation.navigate('Home',{user})
                        }
                                          
                    })
                }
                })
            }
            catch(error){
                console.log(error)
                alert(error)
            }
           
        }
     this.setState({
        newPassword:'',
        currentPassword:''
    }) 
        
    }




    render(){
        return(
            <CustomBackground>                
                        <TextInput  placeholder={'Current Password'} onChangeText={currentPassword=>this.setState({currentPassword})}/>
                        <TextInput placeholder={'New Password'} onChangeText={newPassword=>this.setState({newPassword})}/>


                        <CustomValidationButton onPress={()=>this.ChangePassword()}>
                            <Text>Save changement</Text>
                        </CustomValidationButton>
                    </View>
                </View>
            </CustomBackground>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First: Firebase have error codes which you can use to know the type of error that was committed.

```
try {
  ...
} catch(error) {
console.log(error.code); // Here you'll get the error code from firebase, usually auth/wrong-password
}
```

Second: to empty the fields, you'll need to set the state to empty strings before navigating to the home screen, just this way;

```
if(response){
  this.setState({ new password:. "", current password: "" });
  this.props.navigation.navigate('Home',{user})
}
```

Comment: For the first question, this is what I did, but when I come back on screen, is always here (but after, if I click on the button, I have the message "All the fields are required"

Comment: For the second question, I also did like this, ("try" before this.reauthenticate) but it does not catch the error

Comment: Yea. Because all the fields are required to proceed. The button you clicked actually calls the changePassword function. And you're checking if the fields are empty inside the function.

Comment: I know, I mean that after that I write current and new Password, its updated, and when I go back to this screen, I still see what I wrote before

Comment: Please, make sure the textinput is a type of password.That is, `secureTextEntry`

Comment: yes it is but it still appears when I go back to this screen after the change

Comment: By appearing to the screen, do you mean autofill?